# objective-c | override UIApplication's openURL method using category. how to call original method now?

Tags: objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

HI,

i am using Plus+. it overrides the original UIApplication's openURL method using category. is there a way to use the original UIApplication method ??? how can i do that ?

Comment: Since it's very bad form to override system methods (or any methods) using categories, I'd say dump Plus+ and use something else. Categories are not meant to override methods, they're meant to dynamically enhance library classes with new methods. There is no reliable way for you to call the original method implementation.

Comment: Also, you've used this site for 2 years and have 60+ questions, most of which have multiple answers, but have only accepted 26% of them. That's really bad form too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the original method. Quoting [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html):

> When a category overrides an inherited method, the method in the category can, as usual, invoke the inherited implementation via a message to super. However, **if a category overrides a method that already existed in the category's class, there is no way to invoke the original implementation.**

In general, using categories to override methods in classes you (in this case, Plus+) do not own should be avoided.